# Android don't launch default activity (MainActivity)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a very simple widget application with one single activity (MainActivity).
At the very beginning I've created MainActivity from BlankActivity template. I filled it a bit later with components and I've added it to AndroidManifest.

**The problem is that Android don't launch the activity** (the only one).

What I see when app started is white blank view (with topbar with app-name).

I've put a breakpoint and didn't get to it during debug.

I've tried to set DEFAULT category to MainActivity and without it:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

I've tried to put full or short path to Main Activity:

```
android:name="pl.test.firstwidget.view.MainActivity"

android:name=".view.MainActivity"
```

I'm sure my MainActivity is in view package.

- I've tried to uninstall application from emulator, and install app again, but it didn't help.
- I've tried to install app to another emulator - no success
- I've tried to install app to phone - no success.
- I've tried to clean and rebuild my project - no success.
- I've tried to set DefaultActivity in my AndroidStudio run configuration - no success.
- I've tried to set specified activity (MainActivity) in run configuration - no success.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.test.firstwidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".view.MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package pl.test.firstwidget.view;
(...)

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.ordersNumber) TextView ordersNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.ordersValue) TextView ordersValue;
    @BindView(R.id.lastUpdate) TextView lastUpdate;
    @BindView(R.id.refreshButton) TextView refreshButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        fillView();
    }

    private void fillView() {
        //empty so far    
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.refreshButton)
    public void refresh() {
        //empty so far
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pl.test.firstwidget'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'

    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Does anybody see what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to  override `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` not  [public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) which is intended for api 21+ to persist your activity state across restarts

> Note Same as onCreate(android.os.Bundle) but called for those
>   activities created with the attribute persistableMode set to persistAcrossReboots (in the manifest otherwise it won't get called hence empty view)

About PersistableBundle

> if the activity is being
>   re-initialized after previously being shut down or powered off then
>   this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied to
>   outPersistentState in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it
>   is null.

So use

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    fillView();
}
```

Comment: You mean, it doesn't launch from Android Studio, or when you click the icon on your home screen.

Comment: @PedroVarela op said `What I see when app started is white blank view` and let me add more links (collecting them right now)and info

Comment: remove butterknife

Comment: Oh My God...Thank you! I've removed one parameter from onCreate method and that helped! It seems so simple when you wrote it..

Comment: @mariachi Android framework usually have different constructors, read them carefully because thing like this happens.

Comment: @mariachi i am glad that i could help , happy coding  and i must appreciate , you really did write a structured post, nice job

Answer (score 2):

It seems nothing is wrong.

1. You don't need `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` in the manifest, just `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` should work
2. If you are starting Android development, for now,  remove all references to butterKnife and don't use it yet; just to verify if it runs.
3. change your `onCreate` method as Pavneet_Singh answered, but don't use that super just use:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
    // ..code
}
```

Comment: Ad.1 I've tried - no success.
Ad.2. I'm not starting, just fetched weird issue... ButterKnife doesn't affect issue.
Ad.3. Pavneet_Singh tip helped
Thank you!